# Create circular game board - Rotate not working as I want it to

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to make a game board with p5.js. I want the circular shape of the board to have 60 tiles in total, which means the rotation should be 6 degrees (6*60 = 360 degrees), if I want 60 tiles in a circular shape.

I cannot get this to work, even though I think I'm doing it right. This is essentially what I want to do:

[image]

If I try with `rotate(6)` and no translate (because that apparently completely doesn't work), I get this result:

[image]

Check out my code at https://jsfiddle.net/mortenmoulder/ze6fn3av/ (you might want to resize the window and hit run again) and here:

```
angleMode(DEGREES);
for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
    //translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    rotate(6);

    rect(centerW + 500, centerH, 100, 50);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: I have never used p5.js before.

anyway, i tweaked your code and got pretty close:

```
var tileInnerWidth = 52;
var tileOuterWidth = 57
var tileHeight = 50;

translate(width / 2, height / 2);
for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
    quad(-tileOuterWidth/2, centerH, tileOuterWidth/2, centerH, tileInnerWidth/2, centerH - tileHeight,-tileInnerWidth/2,centerH - tileHeight);
    rotate(6);
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mht3o21p/2/

To explain what i'm doing:

- There's a single translate to move the origin to the middle of the screen, so that rotations can be relative to that
- I draw the trapezoid which goes at the very bottom of the circle. It needs to be centered horizontally, so its x coordinates have division by 2. The sizes were picked by trial and error and what looked good.
- I rotate 6 degrees and repeat.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but they're not next to each other like my example. Also looks like random numbers, if I have to be honest.

Comment: I've improved it as much as can be done while still using rectangles. To get it perfect, you'll need trapezoids

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick. Look at the latest version of the fiddle and see if that does what you need. Some of the values like 52 and 57 seem a bit magic-numbery which i'm not too pleased with, but i gave them names to indicate what their purpose is.

Comment: Oh yeah that looks pretty damn good. Thanks a lot! I wish there was a mathematical way to calculate this, but I can't think of it right now, unfortunately.

Comment: I know how to approximately calculate it, and it should be good enough for your case. If we assume the inner and outer edges are perfect circles (they're not, which is where the approximation comes in), then `tileOuterWidth = (centerH * 2 * Math.PI) / 60`. That gives 57.54, which is close to what i picked through trial and error. And `tileInnerWidth = ((centerH - tileHeight) * 2 * Math.PI) / 60`, which works out to 52.36, again close to my trial and error value.

Comment: Ah yeah okay, that makes sense! Thanks a lot :-D